# How I writte the Update method for a Unit Test with C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm

I have an MVVC project with C# and I'm been having troubles doing the Unit Test for the Update method.

```
public bool Update()
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

    try
    {
        conn = new Conexion().abrirConexion();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("u_usuario_interno", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_name", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = this.Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_surname", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = this.Surname;
        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unittesting means getting rid of dependencies. You use concrete Oracle classes so you can't get rid of the oracle dependency and so you can't unittest this method. Change the method to use the base interfaces for the oracle classes and inject mocks for them instead of the concrete classes. Then you can unittest this method if you still want to. Or do you rather want to do more of an integration test against a real testdatabase instead of a unit test?

Comment: As a marker when you see a "new" in your method you will have problems when unit testing those.

Comment: what exactly would you unit test anyway? There is no logic code of any kind. as a side note, returning true from an update method is pointless. It makes far more sense to return the number of updated rows so you can run integrity checks on what just happened.